# jquery slideIn on element is not working

Tags: jquery, slidedown

I cant seem to get the jQuery slide in method working.

Please have a look at my code below. The other jquery methods are working fine.

HTML:

```
<div id="customers-say">
                <h1>WHAT OUR CUSTOMERS SAY...</h1>  

            </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $("#customers-say").slideDown("slow");

            $("#f1").fadeIn(1000, function(){
                $("#f2").fadeIn(1000, function(){
                    $("#f3").fadeIn(1000, function(){
                        $("#f4").fadeIn(1000);
                    })
                })
            });


        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot apply slideDown event to an element that is already visible it must be hidden initially, Slidedown will unhide it slowly.

In your example simple apply this CSS to your element

```
#customers-say {
            background: #de9a44;
            margin: 3px;
            display: none;
            float: left;
      }
```

Comment: ahh, thank you very much Zaigham! I'm new to web development and Jquery so I am making silly mistakes like this, but definately learning from them.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is being displayed before the animation. I added an inline styling to hide all of the elements from the start.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

            $("#customers-say").slideDown("slow");

            $("#f1").fadeIn(1000, function(){
                $("#f2").fadeIn(1000, function(){
                    $("#f3").fadeIn(1000, function(){
                        $("#f4").fadeIn(1000);
                    })
                })
            });


        });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="display:none;" id="customers-say">
                <h1>WHAT OUR CUSTOMERS SAY...</h1>  

            </div>

            <h2 style="display:none;" id="f1">A. Dylan</h2>
            <h2 style="display:none;" id="f2">B. Dylan</h2>
            <h2 style="display:none;" id="f3">C. Dylan</h2>
            <h2 style="display:none;" id="f4">D. because I spit hot fire</h2>
</body>
</html>
```